# C++ modifying struct values from function by reference (potentially compile order issue)

Tags: c++, function, reference, compilation, struct

I've been doing a fair amount of reading on passing a struct member to a function. However if someone could clarify where I am going wrong I would appreciate it. I predict this is more a compile order / definition error than anything, although there may be syntax errors also.

As I understand it, I am able to modify the struct members data, and avoid any copying by passing as a reference (in this case NOT a pointer). This method will also allow me to keep the dotted notation for accessing individual members inside the function.

Main.cpp:

```
// include headers
struct foo{
  int a;
  int b;
}foo_data;

int main(){
  foo_data.a = 1; // assign some values to the member in standard format.
  foo_data.b = 2;

  function(foo_data); 
  // should this be &foo_data, am I passing by value here as it is
  // or is the declaration taking care of that? 
}
```

functions.h:

```
void function(foo &) // function declaration reference of type foo
```

functions.cpp:

```
void function(foo &foo_data) // function definition reference of type foo
{
  foo_data.a; // should == 1
  foo_data.b; // should == 2
}
```

The errors typically relate to undeclared identifiers, being foo_data. Do I need to tell tell the declaration in functions.h I am passing it a struct, or in fact an int (reference?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Root Cause:**
You get the error because compiler does not *know/understand* the type `foo` which you use in your cpp file. It can know the type only if it *sees* its definition.

**Solution:**
You need to put the declaration of the structure in a header file and include that header file in both the header where you declare the function and the cpp file where you define it.

**functions.h**

```
struct foo{
int a;
int b;
};
extern foo foo_data;
void function(foo &);
```

**functions.cpp**

```
#include "functions.h"
foo foo_data;


void function(foo &foo_data) function definition reference of type foo
{
    //access local foo_data
    foo_data.a // should = 1
    foo_data.b // should = 2

    //access global foo_data
    ::foo_data.a = 1;
    ::foo_data.b = 1;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "functions.h"

int main()
{
    //Global foo_data is accessible here now
    foo_data.a = 
    foo_data.a =
    ....
}
```

**EDIT:**
Your comments suggest you want to share a `foo_data` instance across multiple source files, in that case you should use `extern`, I modified the above code sample to do so, note that inside `function()` the local `foo_data` instance will hide the global instance and to if you want to use the global object then you have to use it as `::foo_data`.

Comment: Hi, it was in fact a design issue, moving the struct into the .h file and re-ordering includes got it to compile. I now have an link error relating to the struct already existing in main.obj - After searching I have found that this is relating to multiple .cpp files being unable to use the same instance. Assigning "static struct" in my .h works, however can I make this struct global? "extern" causes similar errors, and is this even best practice? Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisJones: If you need to share the same global object across different files then yes you have to use `extern`, I don't see where you are using a global though.

Comment: Hi, if my header file is included in EITHER main.cpp, OR functions.cpp then it compiles and links. If it is included in both files, then I get the following link error:  functions.obj : error LNK2005: "struct Foo foo_data" (?foo_data@@3UFoo@@A) already defined in main.obj - I am including my .h immediately after precompiled includes.

Comment: @ChrisJones: Check the updated answer and comments in the code.It should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a go and let you know how I get on. Is this method best practice for modifying a struct from several .cpp files, or not? i.e is this sort of thing typically done using pointers instead?

Comment: @ChrisJones: Usually if you can pass around objects through functions then that is the best way to do things.Global objects are usually avoided because if you use them in multithreaded environment then you need to synchronize access to them. To sum it up,there is no fixed way, both have their own advantages & disadvantages, the one which suits your requirement is what is chosen.Simply put, its horses for courses.

Answer (score 2):

The class definition for `foo` must be visible to both `main` and `function`. Do it like this:

```
// File foo.hpp

struct foo { int a; int b; };
void function(foo &);
```

```
// File main.cpp

#include "foo.hpp"

int main()
{
    foo foo_data;
    foo_data.a = 1;
    function(foo_data);
}
```

```
// File foo.cpp

#include "foo.hpp"

void function(foo & x)
{
     // use x.a, x.b etc.
}
```

If your `function` only needs to *read* the values, you can declare it with a `foo const &` argument.